# Remove last comma when listing tags wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following script to list a post's tags without links, but it puts a comma after all of the tags including the last one. Is there any way to prevent the script from adding a comma to the last tag in the list? I tried researching it, but there really isn't a whole lot out there about this particular wp string.

```
<?php
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            echo $tag->name . ', '; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use rtrim. It will trim the last specified character.

```
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {
       $taglist = "";
       foreach($posttags as $tag) {
           $taglist .=  $tag->name . ', '; 
       }
      echo rtrim($taglist, ", ");
   }
```

Comment: I didn't test it yet, but I fear it doesn't work, because the most-right character is not a `,` ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($posttags) {
    echo implode(
        ', ', 
        array_map(
            function($tag) { return $tag->name; },
            $posttags
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: If I add that line in lieu of my current if, no tags are displayed.

Comment: @ThomasNolan When you do what?! O_o

Comment: @KingCrunch - He is trying to implode $posttags[n]->name

Comment: I figured out what I did wrong with yours. This solution does work as well. I deleted something that should not have been when trying to implement it the first time. Sorry!

Comment: @janenz00 Updated. Well, got a little bit ugly (not everybody like `array_map()` ;)), but the idea should be clear :) It's slightly "cleaner" to use `implode()` (because thats the reason it exists).

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do this when I need to concat a variable number of elements.

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        $temp[] = $tag->name; 
    }
}
if (!empty($temp)) echo implode(', ',$temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the placement of that Comma and put a small condition

```
<?php
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags)
    {
        $first=true;
        foreach($posttags as $tag) 
        {
            if($first)
            {
                echo $tag->name; 
                $first=false;
            }
            else
            {
                echo ', '.$tag->name; 
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the wordpress function [`the_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags). It will echo a tags so you won't need the whole loop.

Comment: Yeah I needed the whole loop because I did not want the hyperlinks associated with the tags that are echoed when using `the_tags`

Comment: Ahh, then my answer is useless